# LearnDash: How to authenticate API call?

Tags: wordpress, authentication, learndash

I need to call LearnDash API from the WordPress
for example like this:

```
wp_remote_request ('https://mywpsite/wp-json/ldlms/v1/groups', $arg);
```

LearnDash API is protected, so I'm getting 401 response:

> {"code":"rest_forbidden","message":"Tut mir leid, aber Sie haben keine Berechtigung das zu tun.","data":{"status":401}}

In the LearnDash API docs, there is no information how one can authenticate call
(Which auth header use, what kind of authentication, etc).

How can I authenticate the call to LearnDash ?

I'm not WordPress expert, but may be there is a standard way to make such authenticated call to plugins' API?

P.S.: LearnDash is installed in same WordPress installation I need to make a call from, I can't call functions directly, at least I didn't find required functions in LearnDash docs.

Comment: Did you get any answer to the question? I am also facing the same issue

Comment: me too, so weird.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because you are not authenticated for that API route.

first install [WP REST API](https://cl.wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/) plugin in wordpress

then you must use JWT token for example in PHP you can use `firebase/php-jwt`

```bash
composer require firebase/php-jwt
```

Code example:

```php
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'; // Include the JWT library

use Firebase\JWT\JWT;

// Your secret key for signing the token
$secret_key = 'your-secret-key';

// Payload data (you can customize this according to your needs)
$payload = array(
    "iss" => "mywpsite.com",
    "aud" => "mywpsite",
    "iat" => time(),
    "exp" => time() + 3600, // Token expiration time (1 hour from now)
    // Add any other relevant data here
);

// Generate the JWT token
$token = JWT::encode($payload, $secret_key);

// Prepare the request headers
$headers = array(
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token,
    'Content-Type: application/json',
);

// Make the API request
$api_url = 'https://mywpsite/wp-json/ldlms/v1/groups';
$ch = curl_init($api_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($response);

?>
```

Pay attention that the generated jwt token is placed in the Authorization header.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use a basic JWT auth, such as this one: https://cl.wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/

Then, you need to include your authentication as a middleware, to retrieve the corresponding token and send it with your request to the Learndash endpoint.

In nextjs, I use this code:

```
export async function getCourseContent(id) {
  try {
    const token = await AuthJWT()
    const url = `https://yourserver.com/wp-json/ldlms/v2/sfwd-lessons?course=${id}`

    const courseSteps = await axios.get(url, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    })

    return courseSteps.data
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error, 'error')
  }
}

export async function AuthJWT() {
  try {

    const credentials = {
      username: process.env.EMAIL_ADMIN,
      password: process.env.PASSWORD_ADMIN
    }
    // console.log(credentials, 'credentials')
    const headers = {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }


    const getToken = await axios.post('https://yourserver.com/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token',
      credentials,
      headers)
    // console.log(getToken.data.token, 'from authjwt')
    return getToken.data.token

  } catch (error) {
    return console.log('error', error)
  }

}
```